# Where to get rpc server ethereum

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I am new to cryptocurrency development.Today I learned that the ETH transaction requires an RPC server. I found a list of RPC servers like Binance. But is there any official RPC server? Or do you need to create it yourself? What is the difference? Where to get the official exchange rate eth to USD? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is no official centralised server, because peer-to-peer cryptocurrencies are about decentralisation. Creating single points of failure is bad.

Ethereum software-as-a-service node alternatives can found on:

https://ethereumnodes.com

I also recommend you to [try to host the node yourself](https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1370323189486784513).

Comment: Hello friend, I also found such a resource rpc.info. 
Please tell me if I connect https://rpc.ankr.com/eth to my application, and the person to whom I will send ETH will be https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/...
Will he get ETH in his wallet?

Comment: Yes, it does not matter what RPC server you use. They all are connected to the same blockchain.